# MSTest V2 Execute UnitTests sequentially -> [DoNotParallelize]

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, mstest

I have a question on running UnitTests sequentially. Unfortunately in scenario it is not an option to run them parallel or mock the database. The project is written in .NET core 3.1 and the UnitTests need to execute database operations before and after a Unittest has run.

After reading https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-execute-tests-in-parallel.htm and a lot of other articles about sequential UnitTesting I came up with this (simplified):

BaseClass:

```
namespace XY.Test
{
    [TestClass]
    public class BaseTest: TimerModel
    {
        private static readonly DbCreator Creator = new DbCreator();
        public static readonly DbConnectionManager ConnectionManager = new DbConnectionManager();

        [TestInitialize]
        public void BaseTestInitialize()
        {
            CreateTestData();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void BaseTestCleanup()
        {
            RemoveTestData();
        }

        public void CreateTestData()
        {
            RemoveTestData();
            Creator.ExecuteSqlFromScript(ConnectionManager, @"Resources\CreateTestData.sql");
        }

        public void RemoveTestData()
        {
            Creator.ExecuteSqlFromScript(ConnectionManager, @"Resources\EmptyTestDataTables.sql");
        }
    }
}
```

TestClass:

```
[assembly: Parallelize(Workers = 0, Scope = ExecutionScope.ClassLevel)] //<-- Also tried out Workers = 1 and Scope = ExecutionScope.MethodLevel
namespace XY.Test.Models
{
    [TestClass]
    public class TerminalConfigModelTest: BaseTest
    {
        [TestMethod]
        [DoNotParallelize]
        public void TestMethod1()
        {
            ...
        }

        [TestMethod]
        [DoNotParallelize]
        public void TestMethod2()
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, no matter what I do, the UnitTests are being executed parallel. What do I have to change in order to have them executed sequentially?

When I execute all tests in the test class, the TestInitialize of the base class is called twice before the TestCleanup is run. This causes the CreateTestData method to fail as indexes prevent a double insert of the test data.

What I would expect:

- TestInitialize1 is called
- TestMethod1 is executed
- TestCleanup1 is called
- TestInitialize2 is called
- TestMethod2 is executed
- TestCleanup2 is called
- ...

What happens:

- TestInitialize1 is called
- TestMethod1 is executed
- TestInitialize2 is called before TestCleanup1 is called
- TestMethod2 execution fails

Am I missunderstanding the [DoNotParallelize] option?

Comment: Have you tried just to remove `Parallelize` attribute? And check options in `.runsettings` file

Comment: Yes, I started off without the attribute and tried locking via Monitor.Enter and Monitor.Exit - also didn´t work. Any other idea?

Comment: Also tried setting options in runsettings file and set <MaxCpuCount>1</MaxCpuCount>

Comment: Try to remove `MaxCpuCount` option. You can also change `ExecutionScope` from `ClassLevel` to `MethodLevel`, it might be helpul for `DoNotParallelize` attribute

Comment: I already tried all variations of ExceptionScope settings, also MaxCpuCount wasn´t set initially. Do you have this kind of setup working for one of your projects?

Comment: Parallel execution is optional one, I don't understand why it's still working in your case. You can refer to this [article](https://www.meziantou.net/mstest-v2-execute-tests-in-parallel.htm) for some helpful information

Comment: Hi again! I had already posted this link as part of my question. Thanks for trying to help :-)

Answer (score 1):

Paralelism isn't the problem here, my tests are definitely sequential and [ClassCleanup] also screwed me over. It's just unintuitive and weird, more info [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20150715221034/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ploeh/archive/2007/01/06/classcleanupmayrunlaterthanyouthink.aspx#comments).

I wanted to use [ordered tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/ms182631(v=vs.90)) but it seems it's a legacy functionality only in MSTest-v1 and new versions of Visual Studio don't even support it.

Best thing i can tell you now is just don't use [ClassCleanup].
**Use [TestCleanup] or [AssemblyCleanup].**